# Hierarchy List<custom>, to return tracks

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, algorithm, design-patterns, entity-framework-4

This could be just some logical issue.. or my design issue 
currently having obstacle to keep track of a feature to keep track of the hierarchy

i have a custom class of team

```
  public class Team
    {
        public int PositionID;
        public int? LeaderId;
        public List<Team> Members = new List<Team>();
        public Team(int positionid, int? leaderid)
        {
            PositionID = positionid;
            LeaderId= leaderid;
        }
    }
```

the data generated is presented in a tree like 
nodes is a List

[image: completeteams]

here is my function to get the immediate leader

```
public static Team GetChildNode(List<Team> nodes, int seekId)
{
    Team found = null;
    //store leaders of leader that lead to the seek leader.
    List<Team> Leaders= new List<Team>();

    foreach (Team node in nodes)
    {
        if (found == null)
        {
            if (node.PositionID == seekId)
            {
                found = node;
                return found;
            }
            else
            {
                if (node.Members.Count > 0)
                {
                    return GetChildNode(node.Members, seekId);
                }
            }
        } 
    }
    return found;
 }
```

currently the return will give me back a team with or without Members depending on the data.

while debuging i notice that with this logic above i seems to be hitting the

```
                    return GetChildNode(node.Members, seekId);
```

even after the node is found..

I would like to keep track of the navigation..

The other word this function is returning me the immediate leader.

I would like to get the immediate leader > leader > leader > up till the main leader (where the leader dont have leader)

i would not mind to return a List where the List minimum index of 0 is the main leader and maximum index is the immediate leader

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to write extension class for IEnumarable.

```
static class EnumerableExtension
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSt>> FindNodes<T,TSt>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, IEnumerable<T>> childrenSelector, Func<T,TSt> resultSelector, Func<T, bool> predicate)
    {
        var result = new List<List<TSt>>();

        Action<T, List<TSt>> search = null;
        search = (element, resultStruct) =>
            {
                resultStruct.Add(resultSelector(element));
                if (predicate(element))
                {
                    result.Add(resultStruct);
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (var item in childrenSelector(element))
                    {                            
                        search(item,new List<TSt>(resultStruct));
                    }
                }
            };
        foreach (var v in source)
        {
            search(v, new List<TSt>());
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

First parameter is a source list of teams, second - is selector for childer nodes of your type, third - selector for result (what you whant to select from objects, liderId for example), fourth - condition for filtering (liderId for example).
It is enough universal, and you can wrap function for different methods. 
Usage:
Will return list of leaderId with navigation to team with leaderId equals 100

```
teams.FindNodes(children => children.Members, res => res.LeaderId, con => con.LeaderId == 100);
```

Comment: nice suggestion with this method i seems to be getting the list of hierarchy, I am working on to inject a logic where I track the path from  Member AB to Member CC. preferably returns me AB , AA, CA,CB,CC. ...

Comment: Kind of this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379574%28v=vs.80%29.aspx ?